# The enemy flies through the walls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a code for an enemy that, when he sees my character, will chase him. But when he sees my character and chases him, he goes through objects.There is a box collider 2D on it, but it moves with it. I've already tried everything, I don't know how to fix it. Can you please help fix
Here is my code:

```
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        idleSpeed = speed;

        barDelta = Vector3.Distance(parent.position, barPoint.position);
        bar = UIManager.AddEnemy(this);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, point.position) < positionOfPatrol && angry == false)
        {
            idle = true;
        }

        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) < stoppingDistance)
        {
            angry = true;
            idle = false;
            goBack = false;
        }


        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > stoppingDistance)
        {
            goBack = true;
            angry = false;
        }

        if (idle == true)
        {
            Idle();
        }
        else if (angry == true)
        {
            Angry();
        }
        else if (goBack == true)
        {
            GoBack();
        }
    }

    void Idle()
    {
        if (transform.position.x > point.position.x + positionOfPatrol)
        {
            moveingRight = false;
        }
        else if (transform.position.x < point.position.x - positionOfPatrol)
        {
            moveingRight = true;
        }

        if (moveingRight)
        {
            if (!facingRight) Flip();
            facingRight = true;
            transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
        }
        else
        {
            if (facingRight) Flip();
            facingRight = false;
            transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x - speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
        }
    }

    void Angry()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        speed = idleSpeed + 1;
    }

    void GoBack()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, point.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        speed = idleSpeed;
    }

}
```

Comment: I suspect its a collision detection issue whats the collider of enemy? and the wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use a rigidbody with the collider. The collider does not actually do physics, that is what the rigidbody is for. If you add a rigidbody and set its velocity instead of setting the transform's position, it will not only detect collisions with walls but it will stop moving and do all of the physics you would expect.